# SSRS Open links (Comma Separated) in new window/tab

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report in SSRS with a column that has a comma separated list of IDS (1, 2, 3) Each ID is a link that opens the profile page of that id.

I created all the links in SQL so my value after running the query looks something like

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=4417">4417</a>, <a target="_blank" href="https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=15859">15859</a>, <a target="_blank" href="https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=18533">18533</a>, <a target="_blank" href="https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=56670">56670</a>, <a target="_blank" href="https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=90498">90498</a>, <a target="_blank" href="https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=292347">292347</a>, <a target="_blank" href="https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=381594">381594</a>
```

The report looks good but the target=_blank is not working and all the links are opening in the same window.

What can I do to open these in a new tab/window?

Thanks.

Comment: The normal approach is to use a javascript `window.open` in the `Action -> Go To URL` properties of the text box, though this will not work for you as you want different links within the same textbox.  Can you format your report so that the ID values are detail rows of a table or sub table?

Comment: "format your report so that the ID values are detail rows of a table or sub table" I don't quite get what you mean by this? Can we add some JS in the SQL itself?

Comment: I am assuming you have your list of IDs being displayed within a table on the report, albeit as a comma separated list per group?  If that is the case, you can have a table within one of the text boxes that displays a row per ID.  In this sub-table, you can set the `Go To URL` action to be the javascript link.

Comment: No my query is returning the formatted list with html anchor tags wrapped around each id.

Comment: I understand that, but when it gets to the report, where is it displayed?  In a standalone text box or within a table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180004/discussion-between-iamdave-and-johnnycage).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using JS to open it in a new window.

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open('https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=4417', 'blank', 'scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=990, height=500'));">4417</a>, <a href="javascript:void(window.open('https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=15859', 'blank', 'scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=990, height=500'));">15859</a>, <a href="javascript:void(window.open('https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=18533', 'blank', 'scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=990, height=500'));">18533</a>, <a href="javascript:void(window.open('https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=56670', 'blank', 'scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=990, height=500'));">56670</a>, <a href="javascript:void(window.open('https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=90498', 'blank', 'scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=990, height=500'));">90498</a>, <a href="javascript:void(window.open('https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=292347', 'blank', 'scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=990, height=500'));">292347</a>, <a href="javascript:void(window.open('https://myurl.com/ViewPerson.aspx?PersonID=381594', 'blank', 'scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=990, height=500'));">381594</a>
```

And this is working fine now.

Thanks.